# Bidirectional JavaFX Binding is destroyed by unrelated code

Tags: data-binding, javafx

**Update: Found a easier way to reproduce buggy behavior**

When I setup a bidirectional JavaFX binding between three variables this binding is sometimes destroyed by unrelated code.

I created a small example program which is capable of reproducing the buggy behavior:

In the MainController the binding is setup and three listeners are added to output the new value of the variable:

```
package bug;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private Foo foo;

    @FXML
    private Bar bar;

    private ObjectProperty<Path> pathProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    pathProperty.addListener((observablePath, oldPath,
        newPath) -> {
        System.out.println(newPath);
    });

    foo.pathProperty().addListener((observablePath, oldPath,
        newPath) -> {
        System.out.println(newPath);
    });

    bar.pathProperty().addListener((observablePath, oldPath,
        newPath) -> {
        System.out.println(newPath);
        });

    bar.pathProperty()
        .bindBidirectional(pathProperty);
    foo.pathProperty()
        .bindBidirectional(pathProperty);
    }

}
```

The FooController changes one of the variables using a counter triggered by a button click. Pressing the button should output the same value three times because we setup three listeners. This works as expected as long the value of the DatePicker is not changed. But after that each number is only outputted once.

```
package bug;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;

public class FooController extends Base {

    int counter = 0;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker startDatePicker;

    private ChangeListener<LocalDate> breakThings;

    @FXML
    private void onBugClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pathProperty.set(Paths.get(String.valueOf(counter++)));
    }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    breakThings = (observableDate, oldDate, newDate)->{
        System.out.println("Triggered");
    };  

    startDatePicker.valueProperty().addListener(breakThings);
    }
}
```

Base class of the Foo and Bar controller

```
package bug;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public abstract class Base {

    protected ObjectProperty<Path> pathProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<Path> pathProperty() {
    return pathProperty;
    }

}
```

BarController:

```
package bug;

public class BarController extends Base {

}
```

Foo:

```
package bug;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Foo extends BorderPane {

    private final FooController controller;

    public Foo() {
    controller = new FooController();
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
        "Foo.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Path> pathProperty() {
    return controller.pathProperty();
    }    

}
```

Bar:

```
package bug;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Bar extends BorderPane {

    private final BarController controller;

    public Bar() {
    controller = new BarController();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Path> pathProperty() {
    return controller.pathProperty();
    }

}
```

Expected Output (after four button clicks):

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
6
7
7
7
8
8
8
9
9
9
10
10
10
11
11
11
```

Actual Output (after four button clicks):

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
6
7
7
7
8
8
8
(Select date with DatePicker)
9
10
11
```

Java Version:1.8.0_20

JavaFX Version: 8.0.20-b26

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Why this is happening**

The bi-directional bindings work by creating listeners and registering them with the properties. When the properties are marked as invalid, these listeners are invoked, and the dependent properties' values are changed.

The listeners that the bindings use are [`WeakListener`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/WeakListener.html). These are listeners that only retain weak references to the objects they are observing. Thus if there are no other references to those properties in scope, the properties are eligible for garbage collection. Once they are garbage collected, the listeners no longer have anything to observe and the binding basically disappears. This is in general a good thing, because it prevents memory leaks that would be difficult to track down, but occasionally (as in your example) it creates confusing situations.

In your example, the references to the properties are held by the `MainController`. This controller is instantiated by the `FXMLLoader` (presumably in a `start()` method somewhere) when you invoke `load()`, but you almost certainly don't retain a reference to it beyond the `start()` method, which completes and exits long before the application terminates. Hence your properties are eligible for garbage collection, and when the garbage collector runs, they are cleared from the heap, along with the bindings. I suspect that when you invoke the listener on the `DatePicker`, the memory requirements force the garbage collector to run. If you press the button enough times (it may be many, many times), you should see the same thing happen, even without the `DatePicker`.

**A simpler example**

Here's a simpler example. There are three `IntegerProperty`s whose values are bound together, and a listener on each of them as in your example. Pressing the "Increment" button will increment one directly, and so the listener on each of them should be invoked. If you force garbage collection, by pressing the "Run GC" button, you will "break" the implementation.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BidirectionalBindingDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        IntegerProperty z = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        y.bindBidirectional(x);
        z.bindBidirectional(x);
        ChangeListener<Number> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(x.get()) ;
        x.addListener(listener);
        y.addListener(listener);
        z.addListener(listener);

        Button incrementButton = new Button("Increment");
        incrementButton.setOnAction(event -> x.set(x.get()+1));

        Button gcButton = new Button("Run GC");
        gcButton.setOnAction(event -> System.gc());

        HBox root = new HBox(5, incrementButton, gcButton);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Why this probably won't be an issue in a real application**

In a real application, you rarely create properties that aren't used somewhere in the UI. Typically you would observe a property and when it changes, update the UI in response. This forces the UI component to hold (indirectly) a reference to the property, making it ineligible for garbage collection as long as the UI component is part of the scene graph. In my example, if we add a label to the scene and make its text dependent on the properties:

```
    Label label = new Label();
    label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("x: %s y: %s z:%s", x, y, z));

    HBox root = new HBox(5, button, gcButton, label);
```

then the bindings still hold even after garbage collection.

**If you still need a workaround**

Just occasionally, you do want properties that aren't observed by UI components. In this case, you must make sure they stay in scope as long as they are needed. In your code, try holding a reference to the `MainController` as an instance variable (not a local variable) in your application class.

Comment: Great answer. I cannot test it right now but I am quite sure that it will save my problem. I still need more reputation to vote you up though.